# PHP output for AJAX and non AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Can you give me some advices about using AJAX? I have problem with returning errors and results. User can turn off JavaScript and I need to use both of methods (AJAX and simple POST). So, all of my PHP code looks like:

```
try {
    $category = new ZvsCategory();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    if ($this->ajax) {
        exit($error);
    }
    return $error;
}
if ($this->ajax) {
    exit(true);
}
return true;
```

Is there any best practices in this case?
I will be glad for any links or advices, thanks

Comment: you might want to think about seperate interfaces for ajax and non ajax. the logic for can remain in ZvsCategory for example, but the way the interfaces are contacted should be differently, since the output and/or format is differently.

Comment: @scones, thanks for help. Guess I will do as you say.

Comment: i dont understand exactly what do u want.. but why not simply add some var in `GET` or `POST` like `ajax=1` and then in code just check `if ($_GET['ajax'])` or someting like that?